# Nilpotent Lie subalgebra of Lie algebra of Killing vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with Riemannian metric $g$. Recently I have dealt with some problem which lead me to the following question:

**Can a Lie algebra of Killing vector fields on $M$ has a nilpotent Lie subalgebra which is not abelian?**

I have thought about it a while and no idea has come to my mind. Googling didn't give me an answear either so I would be gratefoul for help/references.

Comment: If $G$ is a (nilpotent) Lie group with a left invariant metric, its Lie algebra is a (nilpotent) Lie algebra of killing vector fields. Now, if $M$ is compact, its isometry group is a compact lie group, and admits therefore a bi-invariant Riemaninan metric. But a non abelian nilpotent Lie algebra

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is a (nilpotent) Lie group with a left invariant metric, its Lie algebra is a (nilpotent) Lie algebra of killing vector fields. So the answer is obviously yes for non compact manifolds.

Now, if $M$ is compact, its isometry group is a compact lie group, and admits therefore a bi-invariant Riemanian metric. Therefore its Lie algebra admits an $ad$-invariant scalar product. But a non abelian nilpotent Lie algebra cannot admits such a scalar product, has the orthogonal of its center would be a Lie subalgebra.

Comment: Left invariant vector filds are generally not killing for left invariant metric because its flows are multiplication from the right !

Comment: OK, take right invariant vector fields so there flow are left multiplicatiin, agree ?

Comment: On the other hand, there are non-abelian nilpotent "metric" Lie algebras, e.g., admitting an ad-invariant nondegenerate bilinear form.